# discord.py wait_for('reaction_add') not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot where the bot asks the user a question in direct messages. It will ask the question, wait for a response, and then use a reaction system to ask if the user would like to submit this answer.

[image]

The idea is if the user reacts with a check mark, the bot will go on to ask the next question, and if the user reacts with a cross, the bot will repeat the question.

However when implementing this, I've ran into an issue where the bot does nothing when reacted to. Here is my code:

```
def message_check(m):
        return m.author.id == user.id
    
def reaction_check(r, u):
        return u.id == user.id

for question in server_info["questions"]:
        while True:
            await user.send(question)
            msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=message_check)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Do you want to submit this answer?", description=msg.content, color=0xff0000)
            reply = await msg.reply(embed=embed)
            await reply.add_reaction("✅")
            await reply.add_reaction("❌")
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=reaction_check)

            if reaction.emoji == "✅":
                break
            elif reaction.emoji == "❌":
                continue
```

I've already looked at a few similar questions on stack overflow. None of these helped me:

[discord.py wait_for('reaction_add') functioning differently with direct messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115501/discord-py-wait-forreaction-add-functioning-differently-with-direct-messages)

[Discord.py: wait_for('reaction_add') not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609338/discord-py-wait-forreaction-add-not-working-as-intended)

I have the server members intent enabled both in the code and on the discord applications page.

Comment: `user` is the person who initiated the ban appeal questions to start

Comment: help me please help

Comment: Could you share some of the debugging code?